# Is there any possibility to test unit test function variable using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react functional component, i need to unit test a function if statement. To simplify my question i need answer for below question.

I have a function like below.

```
function a(){
   const x = null;
   const feat = (x, emi) => {
      if(x){
        // some feature
      }
   }
}
```

Will I be able to spy on **feat** function using jest, also is there any possibility to mock parameter to that function

Comment: why do you want to mock feat function? it's an internal function of a.

Comment: i want set the value of variable x = null or x = some number and see that if block inside code are called or not. Basically how to unit test inner function?

Comment: you need to show more code for that. you can't spy on inner function. you can check side effects which is happening inside your inner function

Comment: Will I be able to change the value of x in any way ?

Comment: how are you calling feat function?

Comment: inside the useEffect() - calling the feat

Comment: Please provide minimal completed code you want to test. Otherwise, we can't decide the test strategy

Comment: No you cannot mock it, it's only visible within the function. . You should always test through the public interface

Comment: You'd want to a.) test the effects of what that function is meant to accomplish, or b.) pass that function in as a prop, and mock the prop in the test.